# Where would reddish purples lie on the spectrum of light, considering red light and purple light are on opposite ends of the visible spectrum?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

Obviously red and purple are opposite on the visible light spectrum. So how do we get colors that are reddish purple? Where would they lie on the spectrum of visible light?

Comment: I wonder, would the visible spectrum form a continuous “color wheel” and where would the shortest and longest visible wavelengths lie ie how red would be the violet, and would the far red look slightly blue-red?

Answer (score 2):

Red and violet are on opposite sides of the spectrum. Purple is not a spectral color at all, meaning there is no single wavelength of light that produces the color purple. Purple is instead a mixture of red and blue. Reddish purple is simply a mixture with more red than blue.

Comment: Couldn’t any visible wavelength shorter than middle blue be conventionally called purple? I believe the fact you are expressing is that there are red/blue mixtures that don’t correspond to the spectrum, but I would contend that there are also red/blue mixtures (purples) that are indistinguishable from specific wavelengths sans analysis.

Comment: No. Violet and purple are perceptually distinct colors. We may not be able to verbally describe the difference (some languages don’t even have a word for violet) but we can definitely visually perceive the difference. Violet stimulates mostly the blue cones while purple stimulates both the blue and red cones strongly. Violet is also difficult to replicate on a computer monitor. Natural violet objects can appear more saturated than is possible to reproduce on a monitor.

Comment: Given the large number of combinations of reds and blues in different relative intensities and precise wavelengths, aren't there at least some shades of violet that would be equivalent to some mixture of red and blue in color theory-that is to say in how they affect the eye? Violet looks redder than blue.  Can you not match its effect on the eye by mixing? What about greens and oranges?  Again, I was of the impression that you could match a spectral green by mixing, but not a mixed green necessarily from a monochromatic, in terms of the effect on the eye.

Comment: This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoLQF3cfxv0 indicates that there are red/blue photon combinations that affect the eye in an identical way to EVERY monochromatic violet.  So my question with regard to the poster's question is, what combination of blue and red would look like the far end of visible violet?  50/50?  80/20?  Different to different observers?

Comment: I am sorry. This is too involved for comments. This forum is designed for straight question and answer. Since it seems that you want a discussion you should go to a discussion forum like physicsforums.com. They have some good discussions about color already: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/the-truth-behind-true-violet.909613/#post-5729503

Comment: You also might want to study the CIE chromaticity diagram, but be aware that a computer monitor cannot accurately produce the diagram.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110229/discussion-between-joseph-hirsch-and-dale).

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing red *and* purple, it could be that your light source is emitting photons at those two frequencies. With the caveat, as pointed out by other answers, that purple is technically not a ('pure') spectral colour.

What I should also add is that what you *see* is not necessarily what it *is*, as your eyes' retinas have [colour/wavelength dependent sensitivities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell) (see plot below). So even a faint red component to the incident light onto your eye will look like a strong signal. Hence, light that has a strong violet component and a residual red component might appear to be reddish-purple because you see the mixture of the two *plus* the retina cell receptors' sensitivity.

[image]

Comment: If you separated light with a prism, would the far red lie dead center red on a color wheel?  Would the far violet be equivalent to an equal mix of red and blue or would it appear bluer or redder in balance?

Comment: @JosephHirsch Well purple is made by mixing red and blue. Different proportions of each give you different shades of purple. So a 'purely purple' light would give you equal proportions of blue and red. If you then double the amount of red, you'd get a (type of) reddish-purple. This is all as measured by a detector, that is equally sensitive to all frequencies. Your eyes are non-linear in their colour response, so the 'reddish-purple' that your eyes see do not correspond to the same reddish-purple from the detector earlier.

Comment: @JosephHirsch From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_purples In color theory, the line of purples or purple boundary is the locus on the edge of the chromaticity diagram formed between extreme spectral red and violet. Except for these endpoints of the line, colors on the line are non-spectral (no monochromatic light source can generate them).

Comment: @PM2Ring I understand that there are mixtures of bluish and reddish light that can not be equivocated to any monochromatic violet light, but I thought that all monochromatic violets could be equivocated to some combination of red and blue such that the color wheel entails the spectrum.  Is that incorrect?  If not, then aren't there necessarily at least some other monochromatic violets that would lie somewhere on the color wheel?

Comment: @PM2Ring https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoLQF3cfxv0 indicates that some colors on the line are equivalent to spectral colors-that you can produce any monochromatic violet by combining the right intensity of some red and some blue, in terms of effect on the eye.

Answer (score 0):

Colours like purple arise when an (purple) objects *absorbs* certain frequencies from any incident light. The 'remaining' reflected light then 'looks' purple to us.